# Must I always unsubscribe from Observables to which I have subscribed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've a component that calls a method from data service which returns observable. Is it mandatory to unsubscribe the observable in the `ngOnDestroy` method?

**Service**

```
public class BlogService {

   public getPosts(): Observable<Array<Post>> {
       return this.http.get('');
   }
}
```

**Component**

```
public class ListComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private blogService: BlogService) {}

   public ngOnInit() {
     this.blogService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not. Completed observables are automatically unsubscribed. Http observables complete after emission.

Comment: An error also causes automatic unsubscription. So in this case, you should only unsubscribe if you fear that the component can be destroyed before the http response comes back, and if you really think having the component stay in memory until the response comes back is a problem. It's most probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary in your case, but can be done as an extra precaution in case you were to change the implementation of your `getPosts` method in future.

In general:

**Finite Observables** such as those returned form Angular Http Client methods do not require you to unsubscribe as they will complete, and at that point will unsubscribe any Observers automatically.

**Infinite Observables** such as an NgRx Store do require you to unsubscribe, as they do not complete.

Answer (score 2):

That is how I handle unsubscribing:

- HttpServices complete after response like ritaj said -> no unsubscribe needed
- Self created Subjects, Observables etc. should be unsubscribed or you complete them by yourself
- async pipe in angular unsubscirbes automatically
- Using observables from libraries -> it depends weather the provided observables completes or not
- Using pipe functions like take(1) or takeUntil can also be used to unsubscribe

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other two answer you only need to unsubscribe from Infinite Observables and not Finite. e.g:

`Infinite Observables —
When you have an infinite sequence, you should unsubscribe, for example when using the interval() or the fromEvent() observables.`

The article below gives examples of scenarios where you do/do not need to unsubscribe.

src: https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3